# jQuery code to validate and stop sending

Tags: php, jquery

I use this jQuery code to validate a file upload event. It's successful. But When I click the submit button I don't want that wrong file to be attached and passed to PHP.

How can I stop the file being sent to server if the file extension is wrong? I want do it using jQuery.

report_file - input field with the type of file

```
var ext = $('#report_file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['doc','docx','gif','jpg','png','xls','xlsx','jpeg','pdf']) == -1) {
    alert('invalid extension!');        
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using **event.preventDefault()** on submit function

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {

 var ext = $('#report_file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['doc','docx','gif','jpg','png','xls','xlsx','jpeg','pdf']) == -1) {
    alert('invalid extension!');  
e.preventDefault();      
}
});
```

This will prevent the form to submit when  invalid extension find.Hope it helps..

**EDIT:**
    Check this fiddle [jsfiddle.net/2yQZY](http://jsfiddle.net/2yQZY)

Comment: This. You can also return false.

Comment: put e.preventDefault() in to my code but it didnt work. I put event instead of e